# Method not found: 'SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode'

Tags: flutter

Today when I compile the flutter project in macOS Big Sur, tell the error message like this:

```
lib/pages/video/page_music_video_player_fullscreen.dart:27:18: Error: Method not found: 'SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode'.
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack, overlays: const [
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/pages/video/page_music_video_player_fullscreen.dart:63:24: Error: Method not found: 'SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode'.
          SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/pages/video/page_music_video_player_fullscreen.dart:69:24: Error: Method not found: 'SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode'.
          SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
```

why would this happen? is it possible to fix this problem? This is the flutter version info:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor                                                                                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is connected. (code -13)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
(base)
```

Comment: which platform are you building it for? was it working earlier?

Comment: I am build for android in macOS Big Sur.@omarwaleed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same exact issue, first to explain the issue:
you are using some plugin that uses flutter 2.5.x or higher
and some features are newly include in the new flutter such as the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode` method.
update to flutter 2.5.x, and the probable should be solved.